# How to choose DISPLAY value for X server programmatically?

Tags: x11, xorg, xserver

I discover a way to run second X server on top of primary with one of:

```
$ xinit ~/.fvwm/xinit -- `command -v Xnest` :1
$ xinit ~/.fvwm/xinit -- `command -v Xephyr` :1
```

How can I find which `DISPLAY` (here is `:1`) is free for use programmatically?

Preferred is solution from command line.

What limits for `DISPALY` value count (hardware/software)?

Answer (score 1):

same limits as for port number ( it's 6000 + display if server is listening on TCP ). Try to bind to a port, if successful - consider it's free, release and start X server with DISPLAY= (port - 6000)